# How do I get my application server CPU to 100%?

Tags: python, linux, operating-system

I have a dedicated application server that does analytics.

I'm running on 2CPU, 8GB RAM machine.

I have two same applications running like below.

```
python do_analytics.py &
python do_analytics.py &
```

However, my CPU is below 20%. Can I run more processes to make full use of my CPU? Will it speed up or my single processes will run slower now since I only have 2 CPU?

Thanks.

Comment: Does your CPU support multithreading? What is profile of your program? Is it performing I/O frequently? Does it use `numpy` or some other native-code libraries to speed up calculations?

Comment: @abukaj, hi, it does I/O and network frequently. It doesn't use numpy. I'm using aws t2.small

Comment: For `t2.small`, 20% utilization is the base performance (see [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/t2-instances.html)). Do you have CPU credits? Or is your question why you don't even reach 20%?

Comment: @stephan, i have 200 CPU credit. I think it's just that I'm not running my CPU to the fullest. Shall I add more processes to run in parallel?

Comment: @moeseth: if it is not AWS throttling your CPU to 20%, then it depends. You have to find out what your bottleneck is and whether it is effectively a serialized operation (eg memory access, a single hard disk or a single web server) or can be parallelized (eg writing to multiple hard disks or multiple web servers ).

Answer (score 0):

The fact that your CPU usage is below 20%, means that your CPU can take more load. So yes you can run more processes.

> Will it speed up or my single processes will run slower now since I only have 2 CPU?

It depends on other factors of what your application is doing. If most of the analytic logic is just using the processing power and memory. You need not worry. But if more process mean more disk access or shared resource. Then running more process may reduce the overall performance.